# Split string from list into a Dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a question about splitting a string that I have inside of a list and adding it to a dictionary. So I have a strings like this inside my list:

```
    '02-Jan-17 Penn State                  49 Southern Cal                52 Pasadena CA'
```

What I want to do is to insert that into a dictionary, but I need to split that string and insert it into a dictionary.

```
    { 
        'Date': '02-Jan-17', 
        'Visiting Team': 'Penn State',
        'Visitor Score': 49,
        'Home Team': 'Southern Cal',
        'Home Score': 52,
        'Location if Neutral': 'Pasadena CA'
    }
```

So this is where it gets a little tricky. The location could be blank so I am not sure I can split on the whitespace or not. I would also need to repeat this for every string in my list preferably putting them all in the same dictionary. I am not sure if that is even possible. I am pretty new with Python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you by any chance working with a .csv file? Because it looks like one. Where do you get the file from. There is probably a format that the file follows.

Comment: you could split according to, say 2 or 3 spaces, then strip and partition your strings. But that's a specific input AND output format. You'd have to show us your attempts, the question is way too specific.

Comment: the fields seems to be wide fixed, aren't they?. If so, could be pretty easy to do it.

Comment: @jbasko if the big gaps are tabulations (we can't be sure of that), yes, that's a CSV file (rather a TSV file). But it's still unspecfied how to split fields in the sub-fields. Which field keeps the space, which data type is integer which is string...

Comment: It is not a .csv file. It actually comes from a <pre> tag in html that I used BeautifulSoup to pull. I then used splitlines() to get each line into it's own string within a list. This all works. Now I need it slightly more granular. Most of what I have found doesn't exactly split it the way I was hoping. Like:
        a = ['xyz=123', 'abc=456']
        d = dict(s.split('=') for s in a)

Comment: If it's in a `<pre>` tag, whitespaces are preserved, so it looks like you're actually working with fixed-width data. I assume you have multiple lines similar to the one in your question...are the fields all lined up nicely in columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you've shown appears to be stored in fixed-width fields. If all of the data is in similarly-sized fields, then you can use the slice operator `[:]` to parse the data.

This program might do what you want:

```
def parse(s):
    return {
        'Date': s[0:9],
        'Visiting Team': s[9:38].strip(),
        'Visitor Score': int(s[38:41]),
        'Home Team': s[41:69].strip(),
        'Home Score': int(s[69:72]),
        'Location if Neutral': s[72:].strip(),
    }

line='02-Jan-17 Penn State                  49 Southern Cal                52 Pasadena CA'

assert parse(line) == {
    'Date': '02-Jan-17',
    'Visiting Team': 'Penn State',
    'Visitor Score': 49,
    'Home Team': 'Southern Cal',
    'Home Score': 52,
    'Location if Neutral': 'Pasadena CA',
}
```

Another possibility is to use a regular expression to parse your data. Here is an example:

```
import re
def parse(s):
    m = re.match(r'''
        (?x)
        (?P<Date>\d+-\w+-\d+)  \s+
        (?P<Visiting_Team>.*?) \s+
        (?P<Visitor_Score>\d+) \s+
        (?P<Home_Team>.*?)     \s+
        (?P<Home_Score>\d+)    \s+
        (?P<Location_if_Neutral>.*)
        ''',
        s)
    return m.groupdict() if m else dict()

line='02-Jan-17 Penn State                  49 Southern Cal                52 Pasadena CA'

assert parse(line)  == {
    'Date': '02-Jan-17',
    'Visiting_Team': 'Penn State',
    'Visitor_Score': '49',
    'Home_Team': 'Southern Cal',
    'Home_Score': '52',
    'Location_if_Neutral': 'Pasadena CA',
}
```

Comment: The first one works great. Exactly what I needed with a little massaging. Hopefully the format doesn't change, but this will do for the dataset I have currently. Thank you.